# Emulating Prolog backtracking in F#

Tags: parsing, f#, prolog, language-design, pattern-matching

I am currently involved in a project to develop an application able to consider a set of nodes and connections and find the shortest path (a common and well-known issue) between two nodes (on allowed connections). Well I don't really have to build an application from zero, but just need to "convert" a Prolog pre-existing application in f#.
I thought I bit about it and finally asked myself one question: "Instead of developing a special purpose solution and implementing new algorithms specifically binded to this problem, can I create a program able to accept facts like Prolog and use them to make queries or something similar?".

By doing so I would create a set of facts (like in Prolog) and then use them to make queries.
So, considering now this new issue (converting Prolog in F#) I need to find a way to create facts like these:

```
myfact1(el1, el2,..., eln).
myfact2(el1, el2,..., elm).
...
myfactk(el1, el2,..., elp).
```

to something in a similar syntax like:

```
fact factname1: el1 el2 ... eln;
fact factname2: el1 el2 ... elm;
...
fact factnamek: el1 el2 ... elp;
```

I know that F# is very well for parsing, so I think that parsing this would probably not be a problem.

OK! Now that it is parsed, I should define an algorithm that, while parsing the code, stores all facts in some sort of knowledge (nothing more than a table). In order to make then all needed associations.

For example a solution might be a hashtable that considers all associations

```
factname1 -> el1
factname1 -> el2
...
factname1 -> eln
factname2 -> el1
factnale2 -> el2
...
factname2 -> elm
factname3 -> el1
...
...
factnamek -> el1
factnamek -> el2
...
factnamek -> elp
```

By doing so I will always be able to solve queries.
For example consider the following Prolog fact

```
mother(A, B) % This means that A is mother of B
mother(C, D)
```

In F# I create

fact mother: A B;
fact mother: C D;

My hashtable is:

mother -> A | B
mother -> C | D

The first col is the fact name and the second is the value (here a tuple).

If I want to search: "who is the mother of B" --> I search for mother, and look for value, I find B, I look in the tuple and discover A!

Well it seems working.
But facts are easy to implement. What about rules?
For example rule parents:

```
parents(A, B, C) :- mother(A, C), father (B, C)
```

In F# using my syntax? Well I came up with this idea:

```
rule parents: A, B, C => mother A C and father B C
```

When my parser encounters a rule, what should it do? I would like to create some sort of record in a table like I did and be able, later, to make queries in order to specify a subject and get its parents or specify a father and get all sons and so on...
What would you do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There [was a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299948/f-and-fuzzy-logic/4300010#4300010) about integrating Prolog-like programs into F# recently.

F# doesn't have any built-in support for performing search based on backtracking (like Prolog). You have essentially two options:

- Re-implement the algorithm in F# using recursion and encoding backtracking yourself.
- Implementing a Prolog interpreter and representing facts using some discriminated union.

To implement shortest path search, I would probably just implement the algorithm directly in F# (using functional programming will be quite convenient and there is no particular reason for using Prolog).

If you wanted to implement an interpreter, you'd probably use a discriminated union that allows you to rewrite your example with parents like this:

```
type Var = Var of string
type Expression = 
  | Binary of string * Expression * Expression
  | Fact of string * Expression list
  | Ref of Var
type Rule =
  | Rule of string * Var list * Expression

/// Simplified syntax for writing And
let And(a, b) = Binary("and", a, b)

let a, b, c = Var("A"), Var("B"), Var("C")
Rule("parents", [a; b; c], 
  And(Fact("mother", [Ref a; Ref c]), Fact("father", [Ref b; Ref c])))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mr Petricek. Just one thing please... Could you edit your answer and post the code you would use to create the discriminated union please? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Andry: Yes, I added a simple type declaration for variables, expressions and rules.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH Mr. Petricek :)

Comment: Ah I noticed one thing: The type Rule seems to be a discriminated union but it has a "member" which takes the same name of the type... is it some recursive union definition? Or what? (as you can see I'm some sort of a newbie here...)

Comment: @Andry: No, this is not a trick - just a discriminated union with only a single case (the name could be anything else). We could use other type for `Var` and `Rule` (e.g. record or F# object), but I used discriminated union, because it makes pattern matching easier. For example, if you were writing function to return number of variables of a rule, you could write `let numVars (Rule(_, args, _)) = args.Length`

Comment: OK! I thought it was something like this, just wanted a confirmation. :)

Answer (score 2):

One good place to start is to look at implementing a Prolog-style unification algorithm in F#.  Good pseudo-code or LISP implementations can be found in a number of general A.I. textbooks or on the web.  You can work outwards from that to the backtracking and syntax.  A unification algorithm should be fairly straightforward to implement in a feature-rich language like F# (though perhaps a bit arcane).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions... I am sorry for this bu... what is a unification algorithm? I guess it might be something useful so please forgive my bad knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, I knew a guy who wrote an [EDSL for Prolog in C++](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~yannis/lc++/).  He keeps meaning to do the same thing for F#, but never quite finds the time.  He seems to recall the basic prolog unification & backtracking algorithm is very straightforward (an exercise in a late chapter of a popular Scheme text, perhaps?) and hopes someone will beat him to the punch, since he's on vacation.  :)