# Looking for example of design patterns baked into programming languages

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages

Many programming languages embed design patterns right into the language. I'm looking for the most obvious examples, like Python decorators (Decorator?) or C# events (Observer). Can you give me some more?

Comment: Java core libs: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns-in-javas-core-libraries/2707195#2707195).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029287/design-pattern-as-missing-language-feature

Answer (score 1):

I've also beein intrigued by this very question and even asked a similar quesiton once: [Design pattern as (missing) language feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4029287/design-pattern-as-missing-language-feature)

Sure, there are some more patterns that simply vanish in other languages.

- Singleton: in Scala, you can define singleton with the `object` keyword.
- Factory: in Smalltalk, classes are first-class and serve de facto as factories for their instances, no need of additional boilerplate.
- Visitor: in Clojure, you have multimethods to help with this problem.
- etc.

Most information about this topic is annectodical. You can check the links in my question. That would be nice to have a more complete coverage of this topic, sadly I've never found one.